# Swapping column data in vba array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a Linear cutting list. Found some code to start with from [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/09/12/cutting-stock-lengths/). I am trying to swap the columns that its calculating the data on (i need to keep my lengths in Col A on my sheet). Right now it is Col A = Qty and Col B = Length. I tried changing some numbers around but not sure how to swap an arrays values.

```
Dim CutArr() As Double
ReDim CutArr(lRowCount - 1, 1)

'Fill array with cuts
For i = 0 To UBound(CutArr, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(CutArr, 2)
        CutArr(i, j) = rInputCuts.Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
    Next j
Next i

'Sort array descending on cut length
For i = 0 To UBound(CutArr, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(CutArr, 1)
        If CutArr(i, 1) < CutArr(j, 1) Then
            temp = CutArr(j, 0)
            temp2 = CutArr(j, 1)
            CutArr(j, 0) = CutArr(i, 0)
            CutArr(j, 1) = CutArr(i, 1)
            CutArr(i, 0) = temp
            CutArr(i, 1) = temp2
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

My ultimate goal is to check if the Length from Col A and Qty of those lengths from Col B match a part # in Col G then check a data sheet to see what that cable's Reel length is. Once it does that it will run this code against all matching cable types and tell me how many Reels i need to buy in Col P.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result might be helpful here, to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BigBen To make it work currently I have quantities in column A and lengths in column B and its checks against the reel length in column O. Example. Qty = 5 - Length = 800 will equal 5 Reels when the reel length is set to 1000. Meaning its 4000 total feet of cable but since the cable comes in 1000 ft reels i actually need to order 5 reels. All i want to do is change the code so Length is col A and Qty is col B.

Comment: This very much sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can explain the *ultimate* goal more, we might be able to recommend a better solution than changing arrays around, which might not be necessary at all.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your file to be processed? Something editable... If you know the range, Excel offers a simple way of loading cells value in an array. Something like that: `Dim CutArr As Variant` then simple load data in this way: `CutArr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G1000").Value`. Of course, instead of 1000 you can determine the last used row. The obtained array is 1 Based Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have two columns, so you can do something like this instead:

```
'Fill array with cuts
For i = 0 To UBound(CutArr, 1)
    CutArr(i, 0) = rInputCuts.Cells(i + 1, 2) 'ColB
    CutArr(i, 1) = rInputCuts.Cells(i + 1, 1) 'ColA
Next i
```